# Linear algebra with large, sparse matrices

Tags: python, scipy, regression, sparse-matrix, least-squares

I want to solve the linear equation Ax = b, for the unknown matrix x. A and b are both large and sparse, and have shapes (when converted to dense) of 30,000 x 25 and 30,000 x 100,000, respectively.

I have tried using both scipy.sparse.linalg.lsqr and scipy.sparse.linalg.lsmr, but they both require that b be dense, which is computationally very expensive and prohibitive.
How can I do this?

Comment: The `sparse.linalg` solvers are (generally) iterative ones, taking a 2d `A` (may be sparse, but doesn't have to be), and 1d `b`.  Looks like you have 100,000 such problems (the 2nd dim of your `b`).  You expect an `x` that is (25,100000).  I suspect that `x` won't be sparse.  It will need all 25 values to solve for the 30000 unknowns of one `b` case.

Comment: I'm a little rusty on least squares calculations, but consider one of those `b` columns.  If `b[:,j]` is sparse, what do all those 0 terms do to the solution?  Seems that they would force `x` to be nearly all 0s.

Comment: https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-1.2.1/reference/generated/scipy.sparse.linalg.lsmr.html#scipy.sparse.linalg.lsmr has a simple example where `b` is 'sparse' (all 0s), and the resulting `x` is also 0s.  Changing the values of `b` doesn't change the required number of iterations.  In  other words, 0's in `b` doesn't change the complexity of the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You could to use numpy.linalg.pinv to find "x" values

Comment: `np.linalg.lstsq` works if `A` and `b` aren't too large for memory.